# inkscape plugin to live edit svg code

Tags: svg, vector-graphics, inkscape

I'm looking for a plugin for inkscape (or any vector based editor for that matter) to see a window with the code next to the window with the graphical objects for SVGs. Both windows would be dynamic, meaning that if you change something in the graphical view it automatically updates the code, and changing the code would automatically update the graphical object. Also it would be nice if selecting an object would highlight the relevant code.

I have had a look here but didn't see anything like this: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Extension_repository

Does anything like this exist or would anyone else be interested in something like this?

Answer (score 4):

you can just use a text editor like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/) to open the svg file. svg is just a set of instructions on how to draw vector lines, and the file is text-based.

You would save the `svg` file edited in notepad++, and then `refresh/re-open` the image in Inkscape to see the changes.    I haven't used Inkscape since writing the original answer, but this should work if a plugin is unavailable.

Comment: This ignores the request to be able to edit both graphically and text and see the result

Comment: It's a little less than ideal, but that's the closest thing I could think of in lieu of a plugin.   I updated the answer to better explain how it would work. 
 @NiKiZe

Answer (score 1):

As Inkscape still doesn't support this, and assuming you are hand editing 'svg' files for inclusion on a website you might be better off using a service like [CodePen](https://codepen.io/).

While it does require internet connectivity it also fulfill's your requirement of seeing the files as they are updated.  A tutorial on editing SVG by hand can be found [here.](http://svgpocketguide.com/book/)