# how to import svg code into Inkscape

Tags: html, svg, inkscape

is it possible to import code into Inkscape and save it as a `.svg` file?

i want to important this code and save it as a svg file:

```
<svg class="defs-only" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<symbol id="wave">    
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
    <g>
    <path d="M100,30 Q70,40 50,30 T0,30 v20 h100Z" 
          style="stroke-linejoin:round; stroke:#f6f6f6" stroke-width="0"/>
    </g>
</svg>
</symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [inkscape plugin to live edit svg code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542775/inkscape-plugin-to-live-edit-svg-code)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Inkscape there's xml text editor (`Edit > XML editor...`) panel. There you can follow these steps:

- Create a new element, call it: `svg:path` (this will create it with an `id`)
- click unindent node to have it as a child from the main node (top one). You may want to keep it under a particular node too.
- On the right hand side fill the list of attributes, by setting the `name` on the box next to the `set` button, and the value in the box below. Once you've enter the values click `Set`. This may seem obvious, but it took me a while to figure it out.

[image: A picture is worth a thousand words]

There's more detailed information about the xml editor on [Tavmjong Bah's Guide to a vector drawing program](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/XML.html)

Comment: Out of interest, in my example I only had a "fill" attribute in the HTML SVG element code. Once I had added the "path" attribute, I found it was then straightforward to drop back to the GUI and add the fills etc. the usual way without having to compose the "style" attribute in this case.

Comment: kind of confusing... maybe these steps are for a previous version.

Comment: With Inkscape 1.1 the same applies till the last point, however, instead of getting a dialogue below the node attributes where you need to `set` the values, you can edit them directly on the node attributes section.

Answer (score 0):

*is it possible to import code into Inkscape and save it as a .svg file?*

Currently unfortunately not by using `ctrl` + `v`. One first has to save that SVG code to a *file.svg* using an external text editor. Then they can open that file in Inkscape, edit, and re-save it.

But it should not be too difficult to implement a script which automates that, for example in Python, using [Pyperclip](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip) or [tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23844754/1658543), for reading the SVG from the clipboard and [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516007/run-process-and-dont-wait) for opening the saved file in Inkscape.